# -bash: ‘export: command not found

Tags: shell, find

Simple bash script finds files and copies them

```
#!/bin/bash
find /Volumes/Backup/SMC\ Media\ Backup/New\ Lifehouse\ -\ Brush\    Creek/Media/ -mtime -1 -exec rsync -r -u  "{}" /Volumes/Backup/SMC\ Frameio/Adolescent/ \;
```

But when run returns,

```
 -bash: ‘export: command not found
```

Comment: This script doesn't have "export" anywhere in it. Are you sure it causes that error?

Comment: Yes. See http://tcokchallenge.com/hostedmedia/bashtemp.png

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't contain `find`, so you're trying to run the file you show as the first argument to `find` in your question as a script. It seems to contains `export` with some backtick or "smart" single quote in it.

Comment: Eliminate a whole class of problem from your shell coding by using `dbl-quotes "..."` for file/path strings including spaces. i.e. `"/Volumes/Backup/SMC Media Backup/New Lifehouse -Brush\"`. That won't solve this problem but make sure you are using ASCII text for `'....'` (single quotes), and `"...."` (dbl quotes). Good luck.